# How to update a user to a queue which is associated with the user using Plugin

Tags: dynamics-crm

I have "User" entity and it has a lookup field called "default queue". I am selecting value from the lookup to "default queue" field.

[image: Below is the image]

After selecting the value, I'm opening a queue record. In queue entity I have a sub grid called members. Here I should see all the users who have this queue associated with them but I'm not able to see the username on this sub grid.

How to resolve this using plugin? I'm new to plugins.

[image]